# Clear terminal in c

Tags: c, terminal, printf

I am facing problem to understand this line of code.

```
printf("\033[2J\033[1;1H");
```

This printf statement is used to clear the terminal in c.
Can anybody explain this to me?

Thanks.

Comment: Google _terminal escape codes_ and _terminal ansi escape codes_

Comment: It sends some unprintable characters to the terminal which tell the terminal to clear it.

Comment: Although the programming language used to output the sequence of characters is C, the function to clear a terminal has nothing to do with C. It is only a potential function of the receiving terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the list of ANSI escape sequences: 
https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797

`ESC[2J` : erases the entire screen

General information:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code